# Problems in installation of Joomla

Tags: joomla, wamp

Hi there everyone im a newbie so can anyone of u help me solve this problem im having in the installation of joomla when im clicking joomla folder for installing it is giving the message: Unable to open WampServer's config file, please change path in index.php file so plz help me to solve this issue coz index.php is in some different lang thanks in advance

Comment: reintall the wamp and then see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try http://bitnami.org/ for some easier installations? And possibly compare those installs with your own manual ones

Comment: cool, didn't know about binami. They also have preinstalled vm images, nice. love those tin cans :)

Answer (score 0):

The way to install joomla on your localhost would be to

1) extract the folder to your www folder. (eg: c:\wamp\www\j15 ).
2) go to the path (127.0.0.1/j15) from a browser.
3) Fairly simple from there.
4) Delete the installation folder.

If you've got issues with WAMP try reinstalling it. If still giving you issues. let us know the errors.

Comment: Agreed. You need to install Joomla into a folder, not the root of WAMP.